# ActiveMQ DB persistent does not reconnect when HA cluster DB failover occurs

Tags: activemq-classic

Whenever HA failover occurs activeMQ broker got stuck with the messages that has and could not restart by itself.

Messages are processed successfully when we restart the activeMQ.

The bean is created to stop and start the connectors in case if `IOExceptions`.

```
bean id="ioExceptionHandler" class="org.apache.activemq.util.DefaultIOExceptionHandler"
        property name="ignoreSQLExceptions"value=false property
        property name="stopStartConnectors" value=true property
    bean
```

We are getting connection closed as exceptions when this failover occurs as below

```
Initiating stop/restart of transports on BrokerService[localhost] due to IO exception, java.io.IOException: The connection is closed. | org.apache.activemq.util.DefaultIOExceptionHandler | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///hostname:52272@8501
java.io.IOException: The connection is closed.
```

Later it is trying to restart the transport connectors as a result of this config, but not able to continue further.

```
INFO  | waiting for broker persistence adapter checkpoint to succeed 
before restarting transports | 
org.apache.activemq.util.DefaultIOExceptionHandler | 
IOExceptionHandler: restart transports.
```

Please let us know if any configuration required for broker to restart and process the messages it has.